# check out and Edit function lost

Tags: sharepoint, checkout, edit

I have created a Document Library which included the Edit and Checkout dropdown button. when this webpart is added to another page it's view changes and you can not edit the documents unless you click and go through to the original Webpart.... Any clue how I get the view to be consistent?

Answer (score 0):

modify the webpart by default its summary view wihich is selcted change it to the all items or the view you want